# Does indirect diagonalization a relativize technique?

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, np, p-vs-np

My main question is can with R.kanon , Fortnow ,... [technique](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/ccc05.pdf) that shows lower bounds for SAT seperate P and NP ?

Baker-Gill-Solovay showed that $P?=NP$ could not be solved with relativization. Does [indirect diagonalization](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/ccc05.pdf) a relativized proof?

Suppose with indirect diagonalization  we show that $NP\not\subset A$ (A is an arbitrary class). how $A‌$ class can be big with indirect diagonalization technique?(I know it is possible that $TISP(n^{1.8},polylog n)=P$ and the bigger class for me is P or $TISP(n^{O(1)},polylog n)=P$ ). we know that $A$ is at least $TISP(n^{1.8},polylog(n))$(class of languages decides with $O(n^{1.8})$ time and $O(polylog(n))$ space simultaneous).

According to Baker-Gill-Solovay proof I think this approach can not seperate P and NP with indirect diagonalization [according this pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-405j-advanced-complexity-theory-spring-2016/lecture-notes/MIT18_405JS16_Relativ.pdf). that mentioned "we will show that such techniques alone cannot prove NP=P"

In special case I want to know that if someone shows $NP\not \subset TISP(n^{O(1)},poly(\log(n)))$ with indirect diagonalization ?

Comment: I don't know what "Does indirect diagonalization a relativized proof?" means.  (Also, "relativization" isn't something you solve a problem with.)  Finally, it's not clear what you mean by "indirect diagonalization", or what is DTISP or SC or A, or what it means for a class to be "big".  I suggest editing the question to state what you are trying to say more carefully and precisely.

Comment: thanks. My main question is can with R.kanon , Fortnow ,... technique that shows lower bounds for SAT seperate P and NP?

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6575/does-diagonalization-captures-the-essence-of-class-separation/6577#6577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buss and Williams codified the technique in their paper [Limits on alternation-trading proofs for time-space lower bounds](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/npProofLimits/paper-journal.pdf), and showed that the best bound that it can give is that SAT cannot be solved in time $n^{2\cos(\pi/7)}$ and space $n^{o(1)}$. This bound had been achieved earlier by Williams in his paper [Alternation-Trading Proofs, Linear Programming,
and Lower Bounds](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/automated-lbs.pdf).